# How to merge duplicate labs on ResearchGate?

Tags: researchgate

In ResearchGate, 2 duplicate labs were created for our lab using the same name. They are exact duplicates, but with different subsets of members. How can I merge them?

<sub>I've read https://help.researchgate.net/hc/en-us/articles/14293170669713-How-to-create-and-edit-a-Lab and https://help.researchgate.net/hc/en-us/articles/14292803187473-Duplicate-profiles but both articles do not apply to my problem.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the documentation indicates you can merge two labs.

If you are the Lab head you can delete the duplicate lab which will free up those members so they can be added to the primary Lab.

[How to leave or delete a Lab](https://help.researchgate.net/hc/en-us/articles/14293172723601-How-to-leave-or-delete-a-Lab)

If there is a compelling reason not to delete one of the Labs, you may wish to contact ResearchGate directly to see if they can assist you.

[ResearchGate Contact Form](https://help.researchgate.net/hc/en-us/requests/new)